# UIFont possible sizes

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, uifont

I am trying in an iPhone app to set the possibility for the user to choose the fonts.

I have already made progress using the UIFont class. Here is my question :
When the choice of a Font within a Font Family is made how to I know the possibilities the user has for the size? Is there a way to list them? I did not see anything like that in the UIFont documentation or anywhere I looked on the net.

Thanks for any piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS uses scalable fonts, and you can specify the size in fractions of points. So there's no way to list the possibilities. Give the user a few good choices or a slider.

Answer (score 1):

Like David Dunham said, fonts are scalable, so you can use the `[UIFont normalSystemFondOfSize:]` method to access a font with any size.  You can also use `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]` if you need to actually change the font used.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that? Clicking the little arrow?

Comment: Close...there is a hollow check mark underneath the vote count and up/down arrows of my answer.  I can send a pic if you need to.

Comment: Ok...added the picture: the hollow check mark is what you click