# Dynamic font size using UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

I have created a nice user interface, and I would like to add some accessibility to it. 
In the settings menu I have added something like that

[image: UISlider for font size]

What I want from this is while I move the slider, the "A" character shown there it will increase/decrease in size. Also all the other fonts in the application will change size as well. I have created a global integer variable called "fontSizeVar" and all the fonts in my application take their font size value from there.

The problem is that I can not make this thing work. First of all it does not change dynamically the size of character "A", and also it does not change the "fontSizeVar" and the text of the rest of the application.

Here is the action call

```
[self.fontSize addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(editFont)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Here is the action

```
-(IBAction)editFont{
[fontTesting setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:self.fontSize.value]];
fontSizeVar = self.fontSize.value;
}
```

Anyone has any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Have you put in NSLogs or breakpoints? Is editFont getting called?

Comment: What values are actually getting put into self.fontSize.value? Do an NSLog of that value. Are they numbers which are valid font sizes?

Comment: Is fontTesting definitely hooked up to the actual 'A' text label btw? You may have defined it as an IBOutlet but not actually hooked it up via interface builder.

Comment: I have used the NSLogs and the values reach the action. I have also hooked the fontTesting via the interface builder.
But again it does not work.

Comment: What I have realised is that the value the I see in NSLog is a real number, for example 16.543. Is that the problem? I mean do the font size takes only integers? and because the slider gives float numbers a problem comes up? How can I make the slider to give only integers?

Comment: Font sizes are floating point.   The item you change the font size of, do you set needsDisplay?

Comment: UIFont sizes can be non-whole numbers, so that wouldn't be the problem. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235852/uifont-possible-sizes for more on that.

Comment: At the start of editFont, add this: 'NSLog(@" fontTesting = %d", fontTesting);' What do you see output? Is it 0 (i.e. nil)?

Comment: @Stripes when I wrote how do I do that it was for needDisplay

Comment: I did the NSLog thing and the value is 16 and changes according to the slider changes

Comment: Ok, that means your label is indeed hooked up, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: [labelObject setNeedsDisplay:YES] is one way (assuming labelObject is what you change the size of)

Comment: @Stripes The setNeedsDisplay does not work. It gives me an error which says "Receiver type UILabel for instance message does not declare a method with selector setNeedsDisplay"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `UIControlEventValueChanged`. Otherwise maybe only the first value is posted.

Font sizes are of type `CGFloat`, so no problem there. Perhaps try to go with `systemFontOfSize:` instead of `fontWithName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your font name from `@"System"` to `@"System Bold"`.

Answer (score 0):

The default font type on iOS is Helvetica.
So to define it for usage:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
```